# In Rails 3.1 How do I create a select list for a form that has a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, haml

GIST is here:
https://gist.github.com/1553371

These are the models I have:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weapons
end

class Weapon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character
end
```

and this is what my view in HAML looks like:

```
= form_for(@weapon) do |f|
  %ul.fields
    %li
      = f.label :character
      = collection_select :weapon, :character_id, Character.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Please Select a Character.'}
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `character_id' for #<Weapon:0x007f9033232088>
```

I've attempted using a string for `character_id`, that also didn't work. The form renders with `:character`, but then of course it won't save back since it needs the `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine, it's likely that you don't have a `character_id` field on your weapon model. If you do then you have pending migrations that need to be run.

You can check the current state of your database by looking at `db/schema.db` it will show if you have the character_id column or not.

You can run your migrations using `rake db:migrate` then use `rake db:test:prepare` to update your test database as well.

If it's not working after running migrations then you'll need to create one, should look something like:

```
# db/migrations/add_character_id_to_weapons.rb
class AddCharacterIdToWeapons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :weapons, :character_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: I was avoiding adding a new migration because the documentation seems to imply that there is some rails magic that should add the _id column automatically and I was afraid of breaking things worse, but this totally works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The api docs:

```
collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So you want

```
f.collection_select( :character_id, Character.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Please Select a Character.'} )
```